# Customize the make command

Tags: c

I want to know how instead of running

```
gcc -std=c99 foo.c -o foo -lcs50
```

I can just run

```
make foo
```

The problem is that when I try it with just the `make` command it says

```
cc     foo.c   -o foo
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_GetString", referenced from:
      _main in crypto-6PNyQP.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [crypto] Error 1
```

But when I include the other flags in using the `gcc` command it works just fine. I am taking an online class and they are able to just type in `make foo` and their output will be

```
jharvard@appliance (~/Desktop): make foo
gcc -ggdb -std=c99 -Wall -Werror    foo.c  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o foo
jharvard@appliance (~/Desktop):
```

I have searched google for a while now trying to find the answer to this question but still no luck.

Comment: Do you have a makefile? Can you show it? If not, writing one is a good start!

Comment: How do your makefile look like? Can you please edit your question to include it?

Comment: Where do I find the makefile I have not made one before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using GNU `make`:

```
make CFLAGS=-std=c99 LDLIBS=-lcs50 foo
```

Or put those macros into a 2-line `makefile`:

```
CFLAGS = -std=c99
LDLIBS = -lcs50
```

For the more complex options you showed in your last example:

```
CFLAGS = -ggdb -std=c99 -Wall -Werror
LDLIBS = -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm
```

With a `makefile` like this, you can build any program `xyz` from a single source file `xyz.c` using just:

```
make xyz
```

When you need to create programs from multiple source files, you'll need a more complex `makefile`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a discussion board (joinable through google groups) that specializes in answering question pertaining to configuration of the CS50 appliance, which is what I assume you are running since you are taking Harvard's CS50 online.

CS50 in a Box (the appliance) should be configured so that when you type make, the 'right' thing happens during the first few homework assignments, so that you don't have to worry about the specifics of compilation right away.

However, if it seems to not be working, you could post a question to the group I mentioned above, "cs50-discuss".
If you are (unadvisedly) using your own setup instead of the appliance, you could simply search for how to make a 'Makefile', the text file which is read by the program 'make' when you run it. Having a Makefile will allow you to ensure that the command that you want to be run is correctly called when you invoke 'make'.